# How to get number of distinct values ? mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

I have this table:

```
rowId --- bussId 
------------------
  1         120
  2         86
  3         86
  4         251
  5         245
  6         301
  7         301
```

I want to get:

1. the number of the distinct bussId values => bussId values
   :count(120,86,251,245,301) = 5
2. the number of the rows which have the same bussId, in the above
   table "the second & the third rows are the same"  and "6 row & 7 row are the same" . so the query
   will return 2.

How could I do that ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to count duplicates, then you can use a subquery:

```
select count(*)
from (select bussid, count(*) as numrows
      from table t
      group by bussid
     ) t
where numrows > 1;
```

You seem to have found the solution to the first problem, but you can put the two together in one query:

```
select count(*) as Answer1, sum(numrows > 1) as Answer2
from (select bussid, count(*) as numrows
      from table t
      group by bussid
     ) t;
```

Answer (score 2):

```
1.) select Count(distinct bussid) from table
2.) select count(bussId) from table Group by bussId having Count(bussId)>1
```

Comment: thank you for your answer, the first one true, but the second one doesn't work correctly I edit the question to clarify it !

Comment: @david look here http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/48066/10 first query return 5, second query return 2

Comment: @SimoneNigro it seems that I want the number of the result from the second query !